# Subquery, for lack of a better term, when using an API written in GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I'm relatively new to GraphQL so please bear with me ...

That said, I'm writing an app in node.js to push/pull data from two disparate systems, one of which has an API written in GraphQL.

For the Graph system, I have, something like, the following types defined for me:

```
Time {
  TimeId: Int
  TaskId: Int
  ProjectId: Int
  Project: [Project]
  TimeInSeconds: Int
  Timestamp: Date
}
```

and

```
Task {
 TaskId: Int
 TaskName: String
 TaskDescription: String
}
```

Where `Project` is another type whose definition isn't important, only that it is included in the type definition as a field...

What I would like to know is if there is a way to write a query for `Time` in such a way that I can include the `Task` type's values in my results in a similar way as the values for the `Project` type are included in the definition?

I am using someone else's API and do not have the ability to define my own custom types. I can write my own limited queries, but I don't know if the limits are set by the devs that wrote the API or my limited ability with GraphQL.

My suspicion is that I cannot and that I will have to query both separately and combine them after the fact, but I wanted to check here just in case.

Comment: When settings the API URL in [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/), what are all the possible query types and fields shown in the docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless the `Time` type exposes some kind of field to fetch the relevant `Task`, you won't be able to query for it within the same request. You **can** include multiple queries within a single GraphQL request; however, they are ran in parallel, which means you won't be able to use the `TaskId` value returned by one query as a variable used in another query.

This sort of problem is best solved by modifying the schema, but if that's not an option then unfortunately the only other option is to make each request sequentially and then combine the results client-side.